# Don't work admin-panel and authorization in laravel5.3's project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I make admin-panel at laravel 5.3.  I try to install sleepingowl 4. All project I make according to the official documentation.All project operate as expected (http://blog.laravel/). But...if I go the link

```
 http://blog.laravel/admin
```

than apache issues :

```
 Not Found

 The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.
```

After I try to use authorization. I make new project which named "auth". But ... if I go the link:

```
 http://auth/signup
```

apache issues too...:

```
 Not Found

 The requested URL /signup was not found on this server.
```

All rights are open to write-rewrite. All my steps according of the oficcial documentation :

```
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation
```

I don't know what I doing wrong. Please, tell me what can I do

There are the links of github:

```
 https://github.com/AlexBukreyev/blog.laravel  - this is my project, where I make admin-panel.

 https://github.com/AlexBukreyev/auth  -  this is project of authorization

 file public /.htaccess:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, it was in the settings of the Apache! You need to connect mod_rewrite through the console:

```
  apache2ctl -M | grep -i rew
  sudo a2enmod rewrite
  sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in `public` directory, there is a file called `.htaccess` (with the dot . at the begining). The content of that file should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Eddy, this file .htaccess  here.